# asmx web service slower after upgrade

Tags: performance, iis-7, iis-6

I am transferring a C# asp.net asmx web service to windows 2008 and iis7 (64 bit), from ii6 (32 bit). I got an approximate web method performance time of about 160 ms before. On iis7, I'm now getting about 320 ms, even after reducing the web method down to almost no code to execute. I realize there is a compilation time on the first call. This timing is after about 20 calls and the time seems has stabilized.

I would like to reduce the time to run the web method from 320 ms to under 200 ms. This is to help handle the case where several calls would need to be processed. Another problem is when I ramp up 20 calls in 1 second, once in a while one of the calls will take about 3 seconds. This is also not desirable.

I've tried compiling in release mode and removed a debug compilation from the web.config. The .asmx file just references the class to load in the dll binary.

Something that is different is that iis7 is configured to show more detailed error messages to help with setup. However, since this is only when an error occurs I don't see how it could be slowing a regular call down.

I've tried both integrated pipeline mode and the classic pipeline mode and still get similar times. I've also tried setting the default compilation language to C#. I've tried checking the ping time to verify it is not the network. IIS has some database connections setup from the time when there was code in the web service method, but now that it does basically nothing I don't believe that should be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fyi - The problem was not asmx, iis7, iis6, debug mode, or the pipeline mode. The new IIS7 64 bit server started off with an internal ip address and then graduated to a public ip address. The ip address made a difference due to differences in network routing. The IIS6 test case was based on a public ip. Once I used the public ip for the IIS7 server the times were reasonably similar.